# primefaces 3.4, p:schedule showing events on wrong dates

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using p:schedule component of primefaces. I getting the events date from Database. The event dates (that are coming from database) are in MM/DD/YYYY format and as following:
04/05/2012
04/12/2012
04/19/201

but when Schedule draws on page, the event are shown on following dates:

04/04/2012
04/11/2012
04/18/2012

I am using the following snippet

```
<p:schedule value="#{fileSubmissionBean.scheduleModel}"
   aspectRatio="3"
   slotMinutes="60"
   draggable="false"/>
```

Any help is appriciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the timeZone in Schedule control of Primefaces, then it works fine.

Try this

```
<div class="row rowSpace">                       
  <p:schedule value="#{fileSubmissionBean.scheduleModel}"
      aspectRatio="3"
      slotMinutes="60"
      draggable="false"
      timeZone="UTC"
      />
 </div>
```

You can have look here for Details [PrimeFaces component Schedule Details](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27946&start=10)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If that alone won't be enough set in your `p:schedule` the `timeZone` attribute,

Like this `<p:schedule timeZone="GMT-X"`...

(replace X with your hour GMT)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at multiple forums I see a lot of suggestions to put timeZone but it is not working because you should put `ignoreTimezone="false"`, just put

```
p:schedule ignoreTimezone="false"
```

Comment: Please improve your answer. I have a very hard time trying to understand what you mean