# <p:schedule> wrong timeFormat with PrimeFaces 5.0

Tags: jsf, date, primefaces, schedule, time-format

I upgraded my PrimeFaces version 4.0 to 5.0 and now the timeFormat in my `<p:schedule>` is not correct.

In 4.0, each event in the calendar had this timeFormat : `3:00 - 5:00`.

For this I have  `timeFormat="HH:mm{ - HH:mm}"`

I don't change anything and then, with 5.0, I have `3:00 -`.

Moreover the start date  and end date are not corrects too. I have two hours less than expected.

Anyone else have this issues ?

Comment: I have the same issues

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried your timeFormat and it works for me! 
For set up correctly start date, just add to `<p:schedule>` this parameter:

```
ignoreTimezone="false"
```

Otherwise I suggest you to take a look to this answer: [primefaces calendar wrong date entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188139/primefaces-3-4-pschedule-showing-events-on-wrong-dates)

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Man you are totally wrong! My post wasn't a thanksgiving answer. I replied to `Anyone else have this issues ?`. Pay attention the next time you add -1 to answer. ;)

Comment: Anyway I edited my post to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm not the -1 by the way. My comment is an automatic one from the low quality review queue. In hindsight I probably reviewed this a bit too quickly, but now that you've fleshed it out into a full answer I don't see a problem here.

Comment: This does not work at all.  I suggest you remove the answer