# PrimeFaces p:schedule start and end time on all views

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I recently upgraded from PrimeFaces 3 to PrimeFaces 5 and my calendar no longer shows the correct display.  I see that PrimeFaces wraps around [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/).

In prime faces 3 I could use the time format

`timeFormat=hh:mmtt {- hh:mmtt}`

to render a start and end time on ALL EVENTS regardless of which view (day, agendaDa, month etc).

Is there a way to do this in Primefaces 5?

Comment: Thanks for referring to the [other Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884636/pschedule-wrong-timeformat-with-primefaces-5-0) btw... And did you try a newer version? 5.0 is 'old' to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an open bug report on github for this:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/190